# Pyspark 3.5 with Postgres as Metastore

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I want to use pyspark 3.5 in combination with postgres as metastore. Somehow I did not find a precise instructions on how to achieve that. I simply installed pyspark and use the `SparkSession` from `pyspark.sql` to build my local spark session. Without this postgres configuration, everything runs smoothly. As I use dagster for orchestration, some logs are from the run execution. Currently I use `enableHiveSupport()` and the following config dict to instantiate my spark session:

```
        spark_config = {
        "spark.jars.packages": "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.0.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4",
        "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog": "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        "spark.sql.warehouse.dir": f"{WAREHOUSE_LOCATION}",
        "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": f"{WAREHOUSE_LOCATION}",
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key": DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY,
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key": DO_SPACES_SECRET_KEY,
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint": f"https://{REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com",
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem",
        "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": f"jdbc:postgresql://{PG_HOST}:{PG_PORT}/{PG_DB}?sslmode=require",
        "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName": "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName": PG_USER,
        "spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword": PG_PASSWORD,
        "datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll": "true",
        }
```

Which results in:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "BONECP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("org.postgresql.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:232)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
        ... 101 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException: The specified datastore driver ("org.postgresql.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:58)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:54)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 103 more
2024-01-26 14:03:41 +0100 - dagster - ERROR - __ASSET_JOB - 4eb893a7-a083-485d-9154-caf4897e96fb - 9577 - spark_test - STEP_FAILURE - Execution of step "spark_test" failed.

dagster._core.errors.DagsterExecutionStepExecutionError: Error occurred while executing op "spark_test"::

pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Stack Trace:
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 54, in op_execution_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_utils/__init__.py", line 467, in iterate_with_context
    next_output = next(iterator)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 131, in _coerce_op_compute_fn_to_iterator
    result = invoke_compute_fn(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 125, in invoke_compute_fn
    return fn(context, **args_to_pass) if context_arg_provided else fn(**args_to_pass)
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/test.py", line 66, in spark_test
    sampleDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("employee")
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1586, in saveAsTable
    self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
    raise converted from None

The above exception occurred during handling of the following exception:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.saveAsTable.
```

There are no tables created in Postgres.

Adding the following

```
        "spark.jars.packages": "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.0.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0",
        "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/path/postgresql-42.6.0.jar",
```

to the config results in the error

```
dagster._core.errors.DagsterExecutionStepExecutionError: Error occurred while executing op "spark_test"::

pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Stack Trace:
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 54, in op_execution_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_utils/__init__.py", line 467, in iterate_with_context
    next_output = next(iterator)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 131, in _coerce_op_compute_fn_to_iterator
    result = invoke_compute_fn(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 125, in invoke_compute_fn
    return fn(context, **args_to_pass) if context_arg_provided else fn(**args_to_pass)
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/test.py", line 66, in spark_test
    sampleDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("employee")
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1586, in saveAsTable
    self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
    raise converted from None

The above exception occurred during handling of the following exception:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o102.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.tableExists(SessionCatalog.scala:514)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:641)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:571)
```

the tables are created within Postgres, but somehow there is a conflict in who is writting in this db I guess.